# How to map JSON data in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I want to map JSON data in key-value manner. I tried it doing on stackblitz but it is showing error.

THE CODE I WROTE:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const sampleJSON = {
  name: "Pluralsight",
  number: 1,
  address: "India",
  website: "https://www.pluralsight.com/"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(sampleJSON).map((key, i) => (
        <p key={i}>
          <span>Key Name: {key}</span>
          <span>Value: {sampleJSON[key]}</span>
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS:

> Error in /turbo_modules/react-dom@17.0.0/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26083:13)
> Target container is not a DOM element.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lyrp91

Comment: "I tried it doing on stackblitz", you should share us the stackblitz itself

Comment: You are mapping the object just fine actually. It's the react component that's giving you issues.

Comment: Check if you have element with ID "app" since default CRA div has id "root"/

Comment: Check if MYSTRING is actually an object or it's string. if it's string, then erase stringify and use parse only

Comment: Can you please put MYSTRING in your question too what you are getting from Backend?

Comment: Thanks Guys for help! i got the mistake of problem part 2. Thanks alot!!

Comment: Thanks, Can you help us by voting the answer that you feel helped you @ThatMediocreCoder,

Comment: I need 15 reputation to vote!! Maybe in future i will!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must export default react components. I got it working in a sandbox ([link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?file=/src/App.js:421-440)), by changing this line

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

to this

```
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your `app component` instead of rendering it to the element id app. The problem is it tries to find element id `app`, but it can't find in the DOM. However `index.js` do the same thing, so you don't have to do the `ReactDOM.render` thing.

> `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));` // you will find this line in index.js, you don't need to do this in app.js

[**Stackblitz Link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lqnybh)

```
import React from "react";

const sampleJSON = {
  name: "Pluralsight",
  number: 1,
  address: "India",
  website: "https://www.pluralsight.com/"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(sampleJSON).map((key, i) => (
        <p key={i}>
          <span>Key Name: {key}</span>
          <span>Value: {sampleJSON[key]}</span>
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set state and then in render function add "map" and return html.

```
  render()
  {
   
    return(
     <div className='training'>
          <div className='items'>
            {
              this.state.training.map( (row,index)=>{
                 return(
                    <h1>{index}</h1>    
                 )                 
              }) 
            }             
          </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```